# DateTime parsed differently in different environments?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I am inserting some data into a SharePoint list (via web services) and on my local machine I set a date field like this (hard coded in this example)

```
<Field Name='TimeOnScene'>" + DateTime.Parse("13/12/2011 1:00").ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ") + "</Field>
```

and it works fine on my local machine, but if I publish it to our web host and run the exact same code I get

```
{"Message":"String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.","StackTrace":"
//
//
 System.DateTimeParse.Parse(String s, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi, DateTimeStyles styles)\r\n   at System.DateTime.Parse(String s)\r\n   "ExceptionType":"System.FormatException"}
```

How is this possible?

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

we also moved from host to another two weeks ago and never had this issue before.

Comment: have you checked what string you are getting for DateTime on web host...

Comment: My guess is the string is in a different culture than the one you're expecting.

Answer (score 2):

Use DateTime.ParseExact instead of Parse, the converting will be like the following code.

```
CurDate = DateTime.ParseExact(YourDateString, "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None)
```

Answer (score 0):

The host could have different local in set on there machine.  in the documentation 
`The string s is parsed using formatting information in the current DateTimeFormatInfo object, which is supplied implicitly by the current thread culture.`